# Wrong SQL query executed in influxDB

Tags: sql, influxdb

[image]
[image]
I execute wrong query with clause Group By but it execute successfully. 
As we know Group By clause used with an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause and throw error.
SELECT * FROM "CSTable"."autogen"."sampleTable" GROUP BY  "NAME" FILL(null)
[image]
So can anyone light on this query and why it is successfully executed in InfluxDB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically it would be the same as if you didn't have the `group by tag` clause. Group by tag does not limit the number of datapoints that influxdb can return, hence it can just return all of them as they are. That is why you are probably not getting an error. Whether an error should be produced in this case is separate question. 
If you however `group by time()` (instead of, or in addition to, a tag) then you would need to provide an aggregate function.

Comment: As in snapshot, NAME column title is difference with others e.g, sampleTable.age...
result should be come NAME as sampleTable.NAME then I will agree with you as you said same result either .

Comment: I'm not sure I got that.
Yes, I do agree that there is a difference in the result, that if you do it without `group by NAME` the column name would be `sampleTable.NAME`; whilst with `group by NAME` the column name is just `NAME`. But that is pretty much the only difference that you see at least on the front end in Grafana. InfluxDB actually structures the raw results a bit differently depending on which version of the query you execute.
Can you maybe try running the same query without the `group by` and compare if you get the same result?

Comment: I already told you that without group by result is coming as I expected e.g. sampleTable.Name with values. Also can you look another snapshot where I get request for records with group by and see how the result structure is different.

Comment: Right, so the result structure is slightly different, however the results themselves are the same, and this is the expected behavior I believe.
I guess it's been cleared then?